# Why are leading spaces stripped from the beginning of attributes names?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Say we have a dummy class in Python 2.7 or 3.5. We want to assign some attributes to an instance:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> x = X()
```

Let's set one variable with leading spaces using `setattr()`:

```
>>> setattr(x, '               foo', 'bar')
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>>> x.__dict__
{'               foo': 'bar'}
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now let's do the same assigning the value directly, without `setattr()`:

```
>>> x.           hello = 'bye'
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>>> x.__dict__
{'               foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'bye'}
#                              ^^^^^
#                leading spaces have been removed!
```

The leading spaces get removed by using the `instance.attribute = value` format!

This last behaviour seems like the desired one after [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) indications:

> **Method Names and Instance Variables**
>
> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

However, we just saw that using `setattr()` allowed us to circumvent this rule. Also, this makes it impossible to get an attribute with leading spaces unless `getattr()` is used, as much as it makes it impossible to assign a variable with leading spaces with the `instance.attr = value` syntax.

Why is this allowed?

Comment: There isn't any leading space in the second case. The spaces are neglected by the parser

Comment: As for why it's allowed, Python subscribes to the adagium "[We're all consenting adults here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)", meaning that Python allows for a lot more than other languages do, with the implicit assumption that developers are not children that need to be protected against themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any whitespace in the second case as the spaces are all discarded in the parsing phase, way before the assignment is done.

Considering Python's emphasis on readability, this can for example allow to run across multiple lines (breaking the line after a dot) and still have working code:

```
>>> str.    \
... lower
<method 'lower' of 'str' objects>
```